# How to install the flash plugin for Chromium on Debian Stretch?

Tags: debian, flash, chromium

Starting from Debian Stretch, the package `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` is missing. After manually installation, however, visiting `chrome://version` shows flash is disabled. How can I install flash plugin for Chromium on Debian Stretch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Debian multimedia archive has the flashplayer-chromium package, which contains the necessary files (notably `libpepflashplayer.so`). Just add

```
deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org stretch main non-free
```

to /etc/apt/sources.list, then

```
apt-get update
apt-get install deb-multimedia-keyring
apt-get install flashplayer-chromium
```

When adding deb-multimedia-keyring either accept the unverified package, or go to http://www.deb-multimedia.org/ for detailed instructions on adding the key manually.

Please note, that this archive contains updated versions of several multimedia related packages, so an `apt-get upgrade` will upgrade some of the standard stretch packages.

Comment: If I am correct this is NOT the official Debian repository and this kind of solution should be discouraged. Just want to point this out to the potential readers.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove comment every line in the sources.list file, but:

deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free

Then, run aptitude update && aptitude search flashplugin-nonfree.

It should find the following packages:

https://packages.debian.org/jessie/flashplugin-nonfree

In the worst case scenario, you can download the package from the above link and install it through a dpkg -i .

Answer (score 0):

It is in testing (buster).

If you don't mind mixing packages. I put `buster` in `sources.list.d`, and in `preferences.list.d` at a low priority.

When I did update and upgrade, it installed `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` automatically.

I no longer get flash upgrade popup in my browser.

Comment: You are not providing a solution to the question

Answer (score 0):

The proper way as 23 october 2018 :

Go to https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ and copy paste the flash version, ex `31.0.0.122`

Download the plugin by example in `~/.mozilla/plugins/libpepflashplayer.so`

Create a new wrapper script to run chromium, by example `~/bin/chromium` :

```
#!/bin/sh

export CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--ppapi-flash-path=~/.mozilla/plugins/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version=31.0.0.122" # <= check mathing fetched version
exec /usr/bin/chromium "$@"
```

Then

```
chmod +x ~/bin/chromium
```

Add `~/bin` in you `PATH` variable in `~/.bashrc` to run it without having to put full PATH. If you use a launcher with <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>, search how to edit `PATH` for your desktop manager.